# Wordpress/Mod_rewrite issue, no error given just a blank white screen?

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

This problem has been driving me nuts the past few hours. Have set up various Wordpress installs before and never encountered this issue. Basically heres the break down.

I was hoping to install a development environment in a subdirectory of an existing website (mainly just for messing around with). The existing website has no connection to the WP install, just thought it would be quick and easy to stick it under there, it appears I was wrong....

Anyway so I have the install working as expected then when I went to turn the permalinks on the whole things goes to pot. I can view the home page of the WP install but any other internal pages just return a blank screen (not when I turn the permalinks off in the settings it works fine).

Thought it was a mod_rewrite issue but I have tried changing the .htaccess rules to send all URLs to google which worked fine, phpinfo() says the modules loaded OK, checked the php error log which doesn't display any errors, so I'm think it might me due to me installing in a subdirectory?

I have noticed that theres plenty of postings about how to do this, including ones in the WP codex itself. However I want to keep the existing website and the wp install completely separate, which none of them seem to address, is it even possible? I would really like to avoid having to setup a new domain.

------- UPDATE ----------

The root directory has no .htaccess file only the subdirectory which the WP is installed in. Its contents are just the WP generated one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /questionmark/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /questionmark/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: It should be fine in a subdirectory. First thing I'm wondering is - Is anything in /.htaccess conflicting with the /wordpress/.htaccess? That's happened to me before.

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file and what's the code inside it? I think you have to exclude the dev directory in the rule-set if the WP install is at root, but have to see it.

Comment: I have added the contents to the above post.

Comment: I just set up a /questionmark/ directory & added this .htaccess into it, but it all works perfectly for me. I added an index.php and went to /questionmark/vgtvbeu.php and it successfully showed me the index.php file. Can you see if that works for you without WP?

Comment: Yes, I see it. There is no reason for the error, it is possible to have more directories under root in this case. Make sure the URLs at general settings are both pointing to the right directory and don't have a trailing slash.

Comment: My god, all that time wasted over an extra slash in the DB. I imported the DB from a dump of a local version, went in manually to change the siteurl and home option_values in wp_options and had a trialing slash. If you want to add it as an answer I will accept. Thanks too Zamphatta, its much appreciated.